# Player walking through objects it shouldn't libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

My player for some reason is able to walk through objects it shouldn't. I am using a 2d boolean array and if the position to the players left is true in the grid, then he shouldn't be able to move and same goes for right. I know for a fact the collision handler is working because all it does is check if there is something to the left or right and if there is it writes **player.setCanMoveLeft** or right to false and the code was working in previous builds. When there is something to the left or right of the player I print out something so I know the collision handler is doing it's job. I just don't understand what is happening here is my Entity update method which player extends,

```
if(!wantsToMoveLeft && !wantsToMoveRight)
    velocity.x = 0;

if(velocity.x > 1){
    velocity.x = 1;
}if(velocity.x<-1)
    velocity.x = -1;

position.x += velocity.x;
spritePosition.x += velocity.x;
position.y += velocity.y;
spritePosition.y += velocity.y;
```

and here is my players update method,

```
if(wantsToMoveRight && canMoveRight)
    velocity.x = 1;
if(wantsToMoveLeft && canMoveLeft)
    velocity.x = -1;

if(wantsToJump && canJump){
    canFall = true;
    velocity.y += 1f;

    if(lastLeft){
        jumpLeft = true;
        jumpRight = false;
    }else{
        jumpRight = true;
        jumpLeft = false;
    }
}else if(canJump == false){
    jumpLeft = false;
    jumpRight = false;
}

super.update();
```

Here is my input listener class too

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if(keycode == Keys.A){
        player.setLastLeft(true);
        player.setLastRight(false);
        player.setWantsToMoveLeft(true);
        player.setWantsToMoveRight(false);
    }

    if(keycode == Keys.D){
        player.setLastRight(true);
        player.setLastLeft(false);
        player.setWantsToMoveRight(true);
        player.setWantsToMoveLeft(false);
    }

    if(keycode == Keys.W){
        player.setWantsToJump(true);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    if(keycode == Keys.A){
        player.setLastLeft(true);
        player.setLastRight(false);
        player.setWantsToMoveLeft(false);
    }
    if(keycode == Keys.D){
        player.setLastRight(true);
        player.setLastLeft(false);
        player.setWantsToMoveRight(false);
    }

    if(keycode == Keys.W){
        player.setWantsToJump(false);
    }
    return false;
}
```

If anyone could help me with this I would be extremely appreciative because I am at a complete loss. If you need any additional information ask for it in the comments. Thank *you!!

***Update*** - If I walk right near the object (before hitting it) and stop (let go of key) then try to repress it it won't let me move(i.e it works if I do this)

***Note*** - That this code I believe worked before I switched to using an **InputListener** this may be false though I can't quite remember but I know for sure it hasn't worked since I switched from using **Gdx.input** in players update to communicating through an **InputListener**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution that I missed has to do with not executing a stop when told he can't move. I can't explain why it was working before and now I need this line of code but here it is, I placed these lines of code in my players update and method and it works beautifully now.

```
if(!canMoveLeft) {
    if(!wantsToMoveRight) {
        velocity.x = 0;
    } else {
        velocity.x = 1;
    }
}

if(!canMoveRight) {
    if(!wantsToMoveLeft) {
        velocity.x = 0;
    } else {
        velocity.x = -1;
    }
}
```

Sorry for anyone who may have gotten confused about this, I got it thanks to anyone who tried to help!